# Computing the signed curvature of a surface in an arbitrary direction

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, curvature

If I have a surface defined as the graph of the function $z = f(x,y)$, is there a closed-form expression for the signed curvature of this surface in an arbitrary direction? That is, if $x(t) = x_0 + t\Delta x$ and $y(t) = y_0 + t\Delta y$, how can I compute the signed curvature of the intersection curve $\mathbf{C}(t) = \big(x(t), y(t), f(x(t), y(t))\big)$ at $t=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the second fundamental form of the surface (at the point $P=(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$) to the unit tangent vector $\mathbf v$ of the curve at the point. See pages 45-47 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

**EDIT**: This is computing the normal curvature (i.e., agrees with the actual space curvature of the plane curve only when the slicing plane is normal to the surface at the point).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: I have one question - would the mean of the curvatures in any two orthogonal directions in the tangent space $T_pS$ at a point $p$ on a surface $S$ always be equal to the mean of the principal curvatures at $p$?

Comment: Yes. See Euler's formula. (See also Exercise 9b on p. 54.)

Comment: Would you be willing to have a look at my most recent post (based on the topic of this post) and see if you can give me some advice? I would very much appreciate it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729884/computing-curvature-along-planar-intersection-curves-on-a-general-surface-z-s?noredirect=1#comment7668477_3729884

Comment: I see now that I misinterpreted your original question. I was telling you the *normal* curvature in a certain tangent direction, which agrees with the actual signed curvature of the curve only when the curve is obtained by slicing with a *normal* plane to the surface. You seem to be wanting the *usual* curvature of the curve, and that is not an invariant just of the surface. What misled me is your referring to *signed curvature*. How are you defining that?

Comment: Ohh I see now that I've also misunderstood the application of the method I used in my latest post. In fact I now realise I don't actually want to calculate the 'normal' curvature. I want to slice a general surface $z = f(x,y)$ with the vertical plane $n_yy=-n_xz$ and compute the curvature of the intersection curve 'in the vertical plane'. Is it possible to compute this as a function of the 'normal' curvature?

Comment: Yes, you can compute the curvature just as a parametrized curve, of course, or you can use Meusnier's Formula (see my answer to your new question). My apologies for the misinterpretation in the first place.

Comment: No need to apologise at all! I am somewhat of a novice in DG (albeit one that's enthusiastic to learn more about DG), so it's understandable that my terminology could have misled you :)
Thanks so much again for the clarification!