# Computing curvature along planar intersection curves on a general surface $z = S(x,y)$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, algebraic-curves, curvature

I am implementing a code that computes the curvature along curves of intersection between vertical planes and parametrised surfaces in 3D. In order to test this code, I have used the surface $S(x,y) = \cos x$ as a test function. The vertical plane P is defined as $y = -\frac{n_x}{n_y}x$ with normal $\mathbf{n}_p = [n_x\ \ n_y\ \ 0]^T$, where $n_x \!=\! -\!\sin\theta$ and $n_y \!=\! \cos\theta$. Here, $\theta\!\in\![0,2\pi]$ is the angle between P and the $xz$-plane that is an input in my code. I have implemented the code, but I am unable to get the correct curvature (I have an alternate means of computing the curvature for the test function because the curve of intersection is a linear scaling of the cos function). I am hoping that if I outline the method I used, someone can point out what I've done wrong. The method I have employed is as follows.

I first define the position vector $\mathbf{s} = [x\ \ y\ \ S(x,y)]^T$ and compute its partial derivatives $\mathbf{s}_x$, $\mathbf{s}_y$, $\mathbf{s}_{xx}$, $\mathbf{s}_{xy}$, and $\mathbf{s}_{yy}$. From this, I compute the unit normal of S as $\mathbf{n}_s = (\mathbf{s}_x\!\times\mathbf{s}_y)/|\mathbf{s}_x\!\times\mathbf{s}_y|$. The tangent along the curve of intersection is then $\mathbf{t} = \mathbf{n}_p\!\times\mathbf{n}_s$.

I then compute the coefficients of the first fundamental form, I, as: $$E=\mathbf{s}_x\!\cdot\mathbf{s}_x,\quad F=\mathbf{s}_x\!\cdot\mathbf{s}_y,\quad G=\mathbf{s}_y\!\cdot\mathbf{s}_y$$ Next, the coefficients of the second fundamental form, II: $$e=\mathbf{s}_{xx}\!\cdot\mathbf{n}_s,\quad f=\mathbf{s}_{xy}\!\cdot\mathbf{n}_s,\quad g=\mathbf{s}_{yy}\!\cdot\mathbf{n}_s$$
The tangent $\mathbf{t}$ of the intersection curve can be expressed as a linear combination of $\mathbf{s}_x$ and $\mathbf{s}_y$:
$$
\mathbf{t} = \left(\mathbf{t}\!\cdot\!\frac{\mathbf{s}_x}{|\mathbf{s}_x|}\right)\!\!\frac{\mathbf{s}_x}{|\mathbf{s}_x|} + \left(\mathbf{t}\!\cdot\!\frac{\mathbf{s}_y}{|\mathbf{s}_y|}\right)\!\!\frac{\mathbf{s}_y}{|\mathbf{s}_y|} = \left(\frac{\mathbf{t}\cdot\mathbf{s}_x}{\mathbf{s}_x\!\cdot\mathbf{s}_x}\right)\!\mathbf{s}_x + \left(\frac{\mathbf{t}\cdot\mathbf{s}_y}{\mathbf{s}_y\!\cdot\mathbf{s}_y}\right)\!\mathbf{s}_y = a\mathbf{s}_x + b\mathbf{s}_y.
$$
Lastly, I compute the normal curvature as:
$$
\kappa_n = \frac{\text{II}}{\text{I}} = \frac{ea^2 + 2fab + gb^2}{Ea^2 + 2Fab + Gb^2}
$$
Is the method outlined above the right way to compute the curvature along the intersection curve? Any help/advice would be very much appreciated!

$\bf{Edit}$: the code just so happens to compute the correct curvature when $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, i.e. at the troughs/peaks of the cos function.

$\bf{Edit}$: It turns out that I don't actually want to be computing the 'normal' curvature in this case, as @Ted Shifrin has clearly pointed out in his answer. I want to be computing the curvature of the intersection curve 'in the vertical plane'.

Comment: Your test function in surface theory $ S(x,y)$ should involve *two* variables. Like $ S(x,y)= \sin x \sin y $

Comment: My test surface is a cosine curve extruded in the direction of the $y$-axis (a "sinusoidal gutter" if you will). Therefore, it is defined by $S(x,y) = \cos x$.

Comment: If you want curvature along curve of intersection then differential calculus, not differential geometry is sufficient.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating in an answer on how to apply differential calculus to compute the curvature for a general intersection curve between a vertical plane and a surface S(x,y)?

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: As a start can you consider $ z(x,y)= \cos x (\cos y ) ^n,\; n$ set  to zero in last step?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why that is necessary. $S(x,y)=\cos x$ is a valid definition of a surface, where $S_y = S_{xy} = S_{yy} = 0$, as one would expect.

Comment: Alright, I responded, please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that I misled you with my answer to your first post, as I misinterpreted the question. What I told you to compute was the *normal* curvature of the curve, which agrees with its curvature precisely when the plane slicing the surface contains the *normal* vector of the surface at the point. However, what gives you the answer is Meusnier's Formula (p. 51) of my text: The usual curvature and the normal curvature are related by
$$\text{II}(\vec v,\vec v) = \kappa_n = \kappa\cos\phi,$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between the principal normal and the surface normal. (The principal normal of your curve is going to be one of the two unit vectors in your slicing plane orthogonal to the tangent vector of the curve. Presumably your *signed* curvature requires that you pick an orientation on the slicing plane — i.e., a choice of normal vector to that plane.)

Your computation presumably gave the correct answer at the points where the slicing plane was actually *normal* to the surface.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had definitely misunderstood what curvature I was needing to compute. So your answer definitely clarified things tremendously for me :)
It also makes so much sense now why I was getting the correct answer at the peaks and troughs of the surface!

Comment: So the function $S(x,y) = \cos x$ now produces the expected curvature with Meusnier's formula. However, if I change the test function to $S(x,y) = xy$, I don't get the correct curvature. (Again, I can compute the analytical curvature by alternate means, because the planar intersection is a linear expansion of $f(x) = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}x^2$ by a factor $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$.) Is there anything in my method above that seems incorrect to you? I have also applied the method from your book by normalising the tangent, and only applying the 2nd fundamental form, and get the same result.

Comment: I can't try to guess what the problem is. There are lots of places errors might occur :)

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not asking about my code. I'm just asking if the maths in my post is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Corrugated surface
$$z = \cos x $$
has by usual differentiation main curvature

$$k_1 = \dfrac{-\cos x }{(1+\sin^2 x)^{1.5}},\;k_2=0;$$
At any orientation with respect to gutter generator direction using Euler's formula:
$$ k_n = k_1 \cos ^2 \psi  $$
It vanishes at $\psi= \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ due to straight extrusions.

EDIT1:

For surface in Monge form, both principal curvatures are obtained (usual symbols of partial derivatives) from the quadratic:

$$ k_n^2 -k_n \dfrac{(1+p^2)t+(1+q^2)r-pqs}{H^2}+\dfrac{rt-s^2}{H^4}=0 $$

Comment: Okay, thank you for this. But this specifically solves the issue for the test surface. I'm looking for a way to compute the normal curvature along intersection curves with arbitrary surfaces $z=S(x,y)$. This is why I chose a differential geometric approach initially. The test surface $S(x,y) = \cos x$ was chosen simply to test if my code was working correctly.